# TableRows change size when content changes

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to build a quiz app, and every time I change the text in a TextView or Button, the relative sizes of the TableRows change.

I have set all the TableRow heights to be 0dp, and all of the enclosed view heights to match_parent, but the heights still change.

The code below is my layout (quiz.xml), which I call from an activity using `setContentView(R.layout.quiz)`.

All of the text is added programmatically.
I'm using Android IDE.

How can I force the TableRows/Buttons/TextViews to maintain their height (even if the text itself is too large)?

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progress_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.34"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice4"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice5"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/explanation_text"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating rows dynamically and populating incoming content ?It might work.

Comment: where is the TableLayout contained? Its height is MATCH_PARENT so it seems there would be space available for multi-line text. You could lock the number of lines with minLines/maxLines/singleLine properties, or assign an explicit height to the rows

Comment: @AjayTakur I have not. Deleting and re-creating most of the page, including buttons, seems like a lot of work for something that only "might" work.

Comment: @rupps The TableLayout is contained in a layout file that is called from an activity. I'd rather find a solution that works irrelevant of the size of the text. I would prefer something that simply stretches the size of the views proportionally to the size of the screen.

Comment: @GercUnderscore could you post an screenshot where the text is too large? Are the rest of weights honored besides the offending textview?

Comment: @rupps I have insufficient reputation to post images. None of the weights appear to be honored. Everything shifts size when the text changes.

Comment: hmm it's hard to tell then... What's happening is, when you change a text in a textview, and the textview has relative size (wrap content/weights...) a requestLayout() is issued and everything is recalculated. That shouldn`t be a problem if the weighted height is big enough to fit the multi-line text, but if it does not, I guess the textview will resize past the calculated height, as the weight is not a hard constraint. As a test, try to mimic the offending behaviour in your layout (set the text contents manually) and see what happens in the GUI editor.